# How to send notification by date and time?

Tags: javascript, php, cron

Administrator creates a notification to users using web page.

When creating a notification, the following information is indicated: title, text, creation date, publication date

How can I automatically send this notification at a certain time (publication date)?

I know that it is possible with the help of cron, but the admin can not climb to the hosting.

Or you can configure cron through your admin panel? Or what other options are there without cron?

Comment: If your hosting does not allow cron (or something similar), *get new hosting*.